# When to use "in theory" vs "theoretically"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Which form is more correct or more readable for writing a scientific article:

In theory D is constant when q tends to infinity.

or

Theoretically D is constant when q tends to infinity.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in theory" in this case?

Comment: This is what theory says: D is constant when q tends to infinity

Comment: I recommend: In theory, D is constant when q tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct forms, but for a scientific article, perhaps:

> Theoretically D is constant when q tends to infinity.

No real reason, but it may be more readable to a not completely scientific audience as well.

Comment: 'Theoretically' has an implication that you are about to contradict it, and is less formal. "Theoretically, they're arriving in 5 minutes... but you and I both that's not going to happen". See, for example, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140465/hypothetically-speaking-vs-theoretically-speaking .